# Bootstrap 3 Radio Buttons Double Toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I am trying to use Bootstrap 3 radio buttons. Things seem to be working fine, other than the `input` elements are never selected.

I found that the `click.bs.button.data-api` event is triggered once, and that calls `$btn.button('toggle')` only once. However, `$.fn.button` is somehow triggered **twice**. As a result, `Button.prototype.toggle` correctly sets the input to its selected state and then deselects it.

Why may `$.fn.button` be run **twice**?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of your issue? preferably in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I tried to reproduce the issue on JS Fiddle, I was able to identify the source of the issue.

This was an application that I was updating from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3. There was a big JS libraries file that contained Bootstrap 2. Running that one along with Bootstrap 3 caused the `toggle` method to be run twice, thus invalidating the selection.

The error went away after removing all of the Bootstrap 2 code.

Comment: To add to this, I had the exact same problem. I narrowed it down to two click events but couldn't figure out why it was firing twice. Turns out bootstrap.min has the buttons plugin rolled in. I removed buttons.js and solved the problem.