# Bootstrap 3 radio requires double clicking

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-switch

On my webpage, I've got a question requiring one answer out of 3 possible choices. But implementing 3 radio (buttons) using Bootstrap 3, I either get no event generated or 2 events generated. If I click on the named label of any of the radio buttons (e.g. "ON" or "OFF"), the button changes but no event is generated. But if I click on the blank half of the radio button, 2 events are generated as the button changes.

This post should answer half of my problem, about the event being triggered twice:
[Bootstrap 3 Radio Buttons Double Toggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709911/bootstrap-3-radio-buttons-double-toggling)
But try as I might, going through my Bootstrap JavaScript files I can't see that I'm using any other version of Bootstrap besides version 3.

I've also read answers where the event listener is doubled up (explaining why they are triggered twice), but that's not the case in my JavaScript as far as I can see.

I've distilled my code and put it on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b5agxjy/3/). Note that this fiddle only generate 1 event per click. I've not been able to find the online URL for all of my .js files. I'd appreciate if anyone could help me find the last missing one: (I have local copies on my machine)

```
https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/js/bootstrap-switch/main.js
```

I know it's not entirely helpful that it doesn't fully replicate the issue, but if someone could help me find the URLs for the above javascript files, that should hopefully help me.

I'm looking to get 1 event reliably generated independently of which half of a radio (button) I click on. If I do away with bootstrap, events are generated each time I click, but there's still 2 events generated for each click..

Comment: It'll be a challenge to help find the answer without an example that produces the issue. These may be the libraries you're looking for Highlight JS
https://highlightjs.org/    Bootstrap Switch  https://github.com/Bttstrp/bootstrap-switch/tree/master/dist   Bootstrap Slider   https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-slider

Comment: @daddygames Thank you, helped me find all but 2 scripts. I've updated the post accordingly, and jsfiddle too.

Comment: Could you use <a href="https://stackblitz.com/">stackblitz.com</a> for the illustrate the problem you have? You can create a javascript blank project and add your main.js file to.

Comment: @SeyhmusGokcen Excellent website! I've added the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hkwst4 Although I can't see why I'm getting a `$ is not defined` error despite having included (and uploaded) my jquery file...?

Comment: @PhilPhil actually stackblitz run over ES6 and you can not import the jquery as old way like you try to make :) Just for information i recover a new stackblitz to descover the ES6 for using Jquery: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3g5kbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call the bootstrap switch two time; one in your main.js file as;

```
$("input[type=\"checkbox\"], input[type=\"radio\"]").not("[data-switch-no-init]").bootstrapSwitch();
```

The second one in your index.js that you made on the stackblitz for each radio button. So when you try to switch the radios the change event fired twice.

For the solution:

I just comment out bootstrap-switch line in the **main.js** file to not to lose the control over the radios and for a simplest usage update the **index.html** and **index.js** files as below;

**Index.html**

```
<table class="overall-table" align="center">
   <thead></thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td><th>Choice: None / Add / Dis:&nbsp;</th></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
           <input id="cbox1" name="GroupedSwitches" class="bootstrap-switch" type="radio" data-off-text="OFF" data-on-text="ON" checked="true" value="none">
           <input id="cbox2" name="GroupedSwitches" class="bootstrap-switch" type="radio" data-off-text="OFF" data-on-text="ON" checked="false" value="add">
           <input id="cbox3" name="GroupedSwitches" class="bootstrap-switch" type="radio" data-off-text="OFF" data-on-text="ON" checked="false" value="dis">
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Index.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $(".bootstrap-switch").bootstrapSwitch({
        'size': 'midi',
        'onSwitchChange': function(event, state){
            console.log("event", event);
            console.log("state", state);
            console.log("this", this); //this mean the checked radio in here
            console.log("checked radio value", $(this).val());
            // Do your logic in here according to the value 
            // if..else..
        }
    });
});
```

Btw, you do not need a form element for the determining the checked event, the switcher made it for you :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I can get the desired behavior now. I don't follow all of the details though, namely when you wrote: `I just comment out bootstrap-switch line in the main.js file` What precisely did you chance? (I can't see how I doubled up my listeners). And I don't have a **main.js** file either, afaik?

Comment: I mean **main.js** file is the bootstrap-switch/main.js which is located under the js folder in the stackblitz that you create before. I do not know, that is your file or not, but actually you do not need to use it in your **index.html** file. When you use it with your **index.js** file that is you switch the radios, that cause the event doubling; one in **main.js** and the other in your **index.js**

Comment: Ahh, Ok now I see what you mean. Thank you!